# Voltage controlled switch simulation

Tags: transistors, switches, npn

I'm trying to short two pins on a chip when an audio signal is received and float them otherwise (same effect as a tactile switch). I thought the best way would be to use a voltage peak holder and a NPN transistor (but is it?). Here's my simulation and I don't think I'm doing it right:

[image]

It looks like I can control the voltage across `R4`, but is this the circuit for shorting and floating two pins? That is, can I connect the two pins across R4 to achieve the effect? My take is that when the transistor is off, there's a voltage at the collector (`V(out_r4n)`). If I were to connect the two pins across `R4`, then the downside pin would be getting a voltage when it's not supposed to. Am I missing something?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: How best to do this depends on the chip, and the functions of those two pins.  Your circuit is unlikely to work.  An opto-coupler might work, and a small relay should work - but more details are required.

Comment: Try changing D1 to a 1N4148, C1 to 10µF, R2 and R3 to 2.2kΩ, and Q1 to 2N2222.  Just a hunch. :)

Comment: @rdtsc Thanks. I've tried those values, but the fact that collector voltage is 3V when the transistor is off seems to be unavoidable. I'm trying to simulate a button press on a remote control. Should the switch pins be connected across `R4` though? If so, a 3V collector voltage when the transistor would be no good - right?

Comment: @PeterBennett Sure. Basically I'm just trying to simulate a button press on a remote when audio signal is detected. Unfortunately the chip number is unreadable. Can I ask why NPN switch wouldn't work here? It's meant to be battery powered, so I'm trying to stay away from relays (all the ones I've seen are fairly power hungry).

Comment: Unless we know what the two pins connect to inside the chip we can't predict what your circuit will do - you are connecting one pin of the chip to the positive supply, and the other to something near the positive supply, or to ground, depending on the state of the transistor.  This may do something very unpleasant to the chip.  Using a relay is safe, because the relay contacts are isolated from the circuit, and will behave exactly like a switch - it won't apply any unexpected voltages to the chip.

Comment: @PeterBennett One terminal of the switch is just connected to positive rail (3V) and the other to an input pin. Would it be a good idea to use a PNP?

Comment: An NPN driving the base of a PNP would probably work.